sqlplus request on multiple servers
I can't seem to be able to write my script correctly.
problem is I don't realy understand how pipes or bash work yet.
I have a script to execute on multiple servers an get the result of each back to my machine then format then etc...
declare -ra serveurs=("a" "b" ... "x" "y" "z")
declare -p result=()
echo ${serveurs[@]}

# setting up a assynchonous task
commande() {
        ssh user@$1 sqlplus -s -l "$dbconnect" localfileToExecuteOnDistServ.sql
}

#send tasks to remote servers
while read -r line; do
        #should get all servers responces
        result+=("$line")
done < <(for s in ${serveurs[@]}; do commande "$s" & done)

#wait for all subroutines
wait

echo ${result[@]}


I can't send the query from my machine to sqlpus.
No such file
EDIT :
user@srv:~/Path$ ./script.sh

bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found
bash: sqlplus : command not found


"I can't send the query from my machine to sqlpus. No such file" -- that's not a good error description. Please tell us precisely what you did (after simplifying as far as possible, see [mcve]) and what the results where. Don't just dump your intention and interpretation here, provide verifiable facts!

Is localfileToExecuteOnDistServ.sh present on all the servers, in the home directory of user? Why put the commande in the background? Where is dbconnect defined? Why use < < ( ) instead of a simple |?

like i said in the description I don't know well bashscript.
so I don't know how to use |
localfileToExecuteOnDistServ.sql is a file on my computer

Look at my SQL answer for a understanding on how to get one query working. You should do that first. Then adding the loop "around" that should be much easier. Good luck.

It looks like sqlplus does not recognise localfileToExecuteOnDistServ.sql as a command or that there is an error in that file. Have  you tried ssh user@a sqlplus -s -l "$dbconnect" localfileToExecuteOnDistServ.sql from the command-line? Does that give the same error?

If I understand well, you're saying that I must have a copy of the query file on each server (which I don't). I can't use a local file to send queries ?

if I wright ssh user@server sqlplus -S -L user/pwd@oracleSrv I still get sqlplus command not found... do I use ssh incorrectly ?

OK so with some testing and tweeking I found that the /etc/profile and . ~/.profile where not loaded.
